# Importing Git Repositories into Linux Eclipse (3.8) and Running/Compiling Them as Java Projects

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, git, github

I am using Eclipse 3.8 for Linux with EGit and am trying to import my Java Git repos from Github. The problem is, they are not recognized as Java projects, and therefore Eclipse does not compile them.

How can I get Eclipse to recognize them as Java projects? Thank you for your answers.

Comment: How have you told Eclipse they're Java projects?

Comment: you might need to check project properties, see whether or not it includes jdk in build path

Comment: @DaveNewton How do I do that? (I'm used to Juno, not 3.8)

Comment: @ay89 I can't figure out how to modify the build path in Eclipse 3.8. (I'm used to Juno, not 3.8). Could you give me version-specific instructions?

Comment: i guess this is the same in 3.8 as well, project properties> java build path>java-build path>libraries>edit

Comment: @ay89 When I open up the project properties, I do not see an option called Java build path. I do see builders, but the Edit button is deactivated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I imported it as a general project. For anyone who gets this problem like I did, never import as a general project on Linux (do it on Windows). Instead, choose to use the project creation wizard. Set the name and everything should go by smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

go through this way:

> eclipse>right click on project>build path>configure.

here you will see a tab called library,

> library>"add library">"jre system library"

you will see as option which jre you want to add. you select execution environment as what ever jre u have installed. thats it.

Comment: I right, clicked and found the build path option, but was told "no actions are available" instead of configure. What can I do?